# Warning Errors and Seasonality Questions for the BFAST Package

Tags: r, time-series

R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31) on x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0

I'm attempting to feed an 11-year time series, at a daily resolution, into the BFAST model to see if it can detect breaks that align with our knowledge of the dates where input data changed. The series itself is actually a difference between an algorithm-derived sea ice extent product for the Arctic and an operational (human drawn) sea ice extent product. Specifically, the difference series is (human product) - (algorithm product) such that all positive values indicate that the human product has more ice, and conversely for the algorithm product. The valid data range is +/- 1*10^6 sq. km and appears as follows:

[image: Difference Series]

And here is the first 90 days of data from the first year of the difference series:

```
Data <- c(-175276.05, -232276.05, -136336.76, 95715.53, 151779.12, 
164566.44, 218769.37, 200736.84, 105887.64, 14426.35, -41969.07, 
69030.93, 73349.8, -27075.22, -142136.15, -136136.15, 1863.85, 
-16761.15, 100394.9, 113368.56, 61704.79, -16002.55, 122554.58, 
-72809.77, -184809.77, -247407.09, -173722.69, -91140.5, -34049.69, 
-158304.83, -175901.74, -211442.38, -180052.53, -174066.45, -70030.18, 
-82030.18, -33284.22, -4265.03, -41862.19, -30639.13, -62305.53, 
-125305.53, -176305.53, -118305.53, 41406.63, 608.19, -100725.02, 
-76505.16, 7763.92, -34151.19, -131002.89, -110096.16, -72502.6, 
80861.21, 58577.95, -28883.35, -203696.82, -273928.14, -285928.14, 
-322928.14, -107873.1, 19767.96, -84003.32, -89605.11, -68633.45, 
-160704.55, -170663.39, -98237.86, -113962.63, 41085.45, 98463.3, 
87798.23, 148593.44, 90224.71, 84678.51, -3096.93, -512.43, -56539.26, 
-51659.94, -5381.75, 155551.74, -35037.1, -118243.32, -155905.59, 
-154578.81, -343272.84, -363430.58, -316900.35, -345670.7, -306597.62)
```

If I feed these data into the bfast package (v1.5.7) with the following code:

```
bfast.fit <- bfast(data, h = 0.30, season = "none", max.iter = 2, breaks = NULL, level = 0.10, type = "OLS-MOSUM")
```

and plot, I do get results. However, there are 'warning' messages that are being thrown that do not come with further description:

```
There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
warnings()
Warning messages:
1: In sqrt(fr) : NaNs produced
2: In sqrt(fr) : NaNs produced
3: In sqrt(fr) : NaNs produced
```

Is there a further explanation for these warnings?

Secondly, I'm unsure if any of the seasonal models would apply to this dataset. Through a Fourier analysis, I know that this time series has multiple seasonality at 335, 185, and 117 days.

Would the dummy or harmonic seasons make sense for this kind of data set?

Comment: I ran the code you have and didn't get the warnings. I had to convert data to a ts object before running bfast, though

Comment: @shuckle Thank you for testing! I'm Confused. I have also tested a number of subsets, but cannot reproduce the problem unless I pass the full time-series (with ~3800 data points) into BFAST. Let me play around some more and follow up on this thread once I have the time to do so.

Comment: @shuckle My best guess is that this is related to the data type being fed into BFAST? I convert the difference series, with NaNs linearly interpolated, to an R series with `Diff_fill_ts = ts(Diff_fill, start = c(2006,01,01), end = c(2016,31,12), frequency = 365)`. For some reason, that truncates the series by about 337 records? If I feed Diff_fill_ts into BFAST then I get the warning messages again. If instead I simply do `Diff_fill_ts = as.ts(Diff_fill)` and pass it through BFAST, no errors are thrown, but time is no longer along the x-axis when plotting results.

Comment: the `start` and `end` arguments in `ts` can only take vectors of length 1 or 2, not 3. that might be what's truncating the series for you

Comment: Ok, changing the start and end vectors to c(YYYY, DOY) stopped the truncation. Warnings are still present but don't seem to be affecting the output of the BFAST function